# VB.Net OOP/DLL List from a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, class, oop

Is it possible in VB.Net Runtime 4.5 to make a DLL, named object, that can be used like this or do I have to use C#?

```
Object.UpdateType.Kind = Object.UpdateType.UpdateTypeOne
Dim x as New Field
x.Name = "Foo"
Object.UpdateType.Fields.Add(X)
```

The real problem I am having is getting the Fields to be a list inside of the UpdateType class.

```
Public Class Object
   Public Class UpdateType
      strFields As New List(Of Field)
      Public Class Field
         strName As String = String.Empty
         Public Property Name As String
            Get
               Return strName
            End Get
            Set (Value As String)
               strName = Value
            End Set
         End Property
      End Class
      Public Const UpdateTypeOne As Byte = 1
      Public Property Kind As Byte
         Get
            Return bytKind
         End Get
         Set (Value as Byte)
            bytKind = Value
         End Set
      End Property
      Public Function Fields As List(Of Field)
         ' This part is not making sense to me!
         Return strFields
      End Function
   End Class
End Class
```

Again as I type Object. I want UpdateType to be a choice in Intellisense.  Once I choose UpdateType from Intellisense I want Kind to be a choice along with Fields.

The kind needs to accept the Object.UpdateType.UpdateTypeOne constant with that syntax and not by just putting the value 1 in its place.

The fields need to be a list or collection of field objects that I can add and remove from in the EXE.  I also want to be able to count the number of items in the fields list or collection.

Thank you in advance!
-Bill

Comment: There is no difference in the capabilities between VB and C# so (almost) anything you can do in one you can do in the other

Comment: Don't use `Object` as your class name - this is a reserved word so will give you headaches

Comment: NET already has a `System.Object` and it is not a good idea to replace it with your own.

Comment: And be careful: VB.NET don´t care about casing, but C# does ...

Comment: Marked as answered because I think I am not asking my question correctly.  As soon as I can come up with the correct words I'll repost.  Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the nested `Class` and `Enum` and just place them all in a namespace. Since `Fields` is a `Public` variable you can access it to add and remove a `Field` object. An `Enum` is an `OOP` way to make choices. Then you can either use an `If Statement` or `Select Case` to find which choice was picked and run separate code for it. See if this what you need.

```
Namespace Utility
 Public Class UpdateObject
  Public Fields As New List(Of Field)
  Public Property _UpdateType As UpdateType = UpdateType.UpdateTypeOne
  Public Property Kind As Byte
 End Class

 Public Class Field
  Public Property Name As String
  '...others
 End Class

 Public Enum UpdateType 
  UpdateTypeOne 
  '...others
 End Enum
End Namespace
```